# jQuery how to toggle multiple class elements and hide different clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html:

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
    @Model.Customer.FirstName @Model.Customer.LastName wrote:
    <span class="right"><span class="icon-file padding-right link"></span></span>
</h4>

<p class="list-group-item-text">@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(log.Description))</p>
<h5>@log.CreatedOn.ToShortDateString() @log.CreatedOn.ToShortTimeString()</h5>

<div class="articleleftmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>@log.Description</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jquery:

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
    $(".articleleftmenu").toggle("drop");
});
```

How can I toggle these different divs? So once 1 toggle one it hides the another one? I am planing to have multiple divs with class name "articleleftmenu" not only 2.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the elements and use the indexes:

```
var $links = $('.link'),
    $articles = $('.articleleftmenu');

$links.on('click', function(){
   var i = $links.index(this);
   $articles.not( $articles.eq(i).toggle('drop') ).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your question but...  Maybe use the JQuery selector to hide all of the divs, then specifically enable the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the jQuery UI Accordian. This may do what you are looking for http://jqueryui.com/accordion/